# blower.io internal server error

Tags: heroku, sms, beta

Is anyone else using the blower.io beta addon with Heroku? I've successfully got it provisioned and got the URL from the environment as per the instructions from https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/blowerio but trying to send any kind of message through it always causes an Internal Server Error.

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Length: 30
Connection: keep-alive

<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
```

This occurs whether I run it from a Resque worker (the aim), the rails console, or even via curl requests.

It gives me no hint as to what is going wrong which is quite frustrating! Any hints or pointers much appreciated.

(Sorry I can't tag this blower.io - I don't have enough reputation to create new tags.)

Comment: You're not alone. Got the same thing.

Comment: @CodySwann (and anyone else who finds this) - we never found a solution and are now using twilio

Comment: Yup. Us, too, actually.

Comment: Same here: Got Internal Server Error from Blower.